# Select a thread in threadpool to shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, shutdown

I currently have a threadpool with 2 fixed threads and each thread creates 2 more threads that perform task. I have it set up to where I can pass commands to stop a thread if needed.

**What I'm asking is if there is a way to select a specific fixed thread from the threadpool and shut it down.**

I have everything set up to shutdown the thread just need a way to select one of the two threads and shut it down and have the other one continue running.

If there is a better way to do this I'm open to other options.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm asking is if there is a way to select a specific fixed thread from the threadpool and shut it down.

Not from the pool itself, no.  Remember that you don't want to kill the *thread* in a thread-pool since there may be more tasks to execute.

> If there is a better way to do this I'm open to other options.

I'd have a `volatile boolean` that is being checked in the task in question so you can cause it to quit.

```
private volatile boolean shutdownSpecificTask;
...
// then inside of your task you'd do something like
while (!shutdownSpecificTask) {
   ...
}
```

The only operations like this that you have at the thread-pool level is to interrupt all of the running threads with a `shutdownNow()` or a `Future.cancel(true)`.  Both of these interrupt the thread which sets the interrupt flag and cause methods that throw `InterruptedException` to do so.

Comment: Thanks this really helps. One question though how would I specify which task is being shutdown? Still relatively new to threads.

Comment: I assume that the two threads are running different tasks @user2448754 so one task would have the boolean test and the other would not.  If this is not the case then you could use an `AtomicBoolean` and do something like `shutdownSpecificTask.compareAndSet(true, false)` which would only shut down one of the two of them.

Comment: They are using the same code to execute their jobs but the jobs they perform will vary.